# Region(area) enclosed between line and parabola

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The problem is to find the area of the region enclosed by the given parabola and line:

$y=-x^2+3x-1$

$y=x-2$

I tried solving the definite integral, but the roots (points of intersection of the parabola and line) on the graph were too weird and I ended up with the wrong solution. Does anyone know a more efficient method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a method where you do not need to find the actual roots from the graph, from which the **problem of "weird points of intersection" will be completely eradicated**. Trust me.

From $-x^2+3x-1=x-2$, $x^2-2x-1=0$.

Letting $a$ and $b$ (where $a<b$) be the solutions of $x^2-2x-1=0$, $a+b=-2$ and $ab=1$, due to the root-coefficient relationship.

Therefore, the area, $S = \int_a^b\left[-x^2+3x-1-\left(x-2\right)\right]dx = -\int_a^b\left(x^2-2x-1\right)dx = -\int_a^b\left(x-a\right)\left(x-b\right)dx = \frac{1}{6}\left(b-a\right)^3$

From $(b-a)^2=(a+b)^2-4ab=8$, $b-a=2\sqrt{2}$

Therefore, $\left(b-a\right)^3=16\sqrt{2}$.

**Thus, the area, $S=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}$.**

And this answer was able to be posted quickly due to my MathJax friend, Desmos.

Comment: Thank you. How did you evaluate that to 1/6(b-a)^3? Did you just solve it?

Comment: $-\int_a^b\left(x-a\right)\left(x-b\right)dx = \frac{1}{6}\left(b-a\right)^3$

You can just solve it, However

$\int_a^b\left(x-a\right)\left(x-b\right)dx = -\frac{1}{6}\left(b-a\right)^3$

Comment: I will upvote now because I have enough reputation, and your answer was useful.

Answer (score 4):

This problem has a nice solution without Calculus.

[image]

Let $P$ and $Q$ the intersections between the given parabola and the given line. Let $T$ be the intersection of the tangents at $P$ and $Q$. By Archimedes' lemma, the area of the wanted parabolic segment is just two thirds of the area of $PQT$. We have $T=(1;3)$ and $PQ=4$ by straightforward computations. The distance of $T$ from the $PQ$ line equals $2\sqrt{2}$, hence $[PQT]=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 4\cdot 2\sqrt{2}=4\sqrt{2}$ and the wanted area equals $\color{blue}{\frac{8}{3}\sqrt{2}}$.

Yet another interesting approach comes from noticing that [Simpson's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpsonsRule.html) is an exact quadrature rule for quadratic polynomials, hence the given problem can be solved by just computing the coordinates of $P,Q$ and by evaluating $-x^2+3x-1$ at $x=1$, since that is the average of the abscissas of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: I will upvote now because I have enough reputation, and your answer was useful.

Answer (score 2):

at the first step you must compute the intersection Points of both functions
this leads to the equation
$$-x^2+2x+1=0$$
can you solve this?
for your Control we get
$$x_1=1-\sqrt{2}$$
$$x_2=1+\sqrt{2}$$
and then the searched area is given by $$A=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} -x^2+3x-1-(x-2)dx$$

Comment: and you should post what you have tried

Comment: it is not a comment, i want do know if the results are ok

Comment: I have already done this method, I just want to find a more efficient method in which I do not have to calculate these values 1-sqrt(2) and 1+sqrt(2)

Comment: but you will Need These Terms!

Comment: You don't have to calculate them; just leave them as is and substitute them in once you've obtained your antiderivative.

Comment: I have solved it without those terms, if you like you can view my solution.

Comment: yeah ok, i know this method! but the next Problem can be complicated and he/she will Need that method

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using your suggested integration method. To find the intersections we set $x^{2}-3x+1=2-x$ so we have $x^{2}-2x-1=0$ so our limits of integration are the solutions to this quadratic namely $x=1\pm\sqrt{2}$.
Now to find the area we want the integral $\int_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}}-x^{2}+2x+1dx=[\frac{x^{3}}{3}+x^{2}+x]_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}$

Comment: I have already tried this method.

Comment: If you simplify the integration (after substituting the values in) you will get to $\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{3}$ the same answer as the alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple integration problem where the required steps are:

1. define your domain by:

   a. finding the graphs intersection points.

   b. understanding which graph is above the other (simple plot always helps).
2. double-integrate "1" over your domain.

In your case, you will have $1-\sqrt{2}$ and $1+\sqrt{2}$ as your intersection points, and within this range the parabola lies above the line, so you have:

$$\int_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}}\int_{x-2}^{-x^2+3x-1} 1 dy dx$$ 
= $$ \int_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}} (-x^2+3x-1)-(x-2)  dx$$ =

$$ (-x^3 / 3 + x^2 + x)\Bigr|_{1-\sqrt{2}}^{1+\sqrt{2}} $$
 $\approx$ 3.77